# ColdFusion 10 Servlet Issues

Tags: tomcat, java, coldfusion, servlets

I'm currently experiencing problems with ColdFusion finding my servlet. In ColdFusion 9, I would simply put it under the wwwroot/WEB-INF/classes/ directory and ColdFusion would serve when requested.

In ColdFusion 10 I've added the same Servlet in the cfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/classes directory (restarting afterwards) and it was not found when explicitly called. I added the descriptor for it in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.myServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

and I'm still unable to call it. Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?